Find the penultimate activity for each user
I have a sample data like below:



Username
Activity
Start Time
End Time




Ace
Dancing
13:00
14:00


Ace
Singing
15:00
16:30


Ace
Yoga
19:00
20:00


Alice
Piano
10:00
11:00


Alice
Hiking
14:00
15:00


Alice
Reading
16:00
16:30


Alice
Swimming
19:00
20:00


Alice
Writing
21:00
21:30


Lion
Fishing
13:00
17:00



I want to find the penultimate activity for each user, if only records one activity, then output that activity, that is, I would like to get the following output:



Username
Penultimate_Act




Ace
Singing


Alice
Swimming


Lion
Fishing



I tried but it cannot get Lion:
SELECT username, activity AS penultimate_act
FROM (
    SELECT
        username,
        activity,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY starttime DESC) AS seq
    FROM activities
) t
WHERE seq = 2;

Then I tried again:
SELECT username, activity AS penultimate_act
FROM (
    SELECT
        username,
        activity,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY starttime DESC) AS seq
    FROM activities
) t
WHERE seq = 2 or seq = 1; 

But it still doesn't quite meet my needs, could anyone provide some help?(If you haven’t heard of my database, you can use PostgreSQL to demo instead. Thank You!)

I would keep the query you have and then add a second query to fetch those usernames with their activity which appear once only. You can combine the two queries with UNION ALL.
Use a GROUP BY clause with HAVING to select only those usernames occuring only once:
-- your existing query...
UNION ALL
SELECT username, MAX(activity)
FROM activities
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;

Note: It might be faster to use ROW_NUMBER rather than DENSE_RANK in your query.
Both will produce the expected result for your sample data:



Username
Penultimate_Act




Ace
Singing


Alice
Swimming


Lion
Fishing



See the demo.

You can use NOT EXISTS, its performance will be better:
https://dbfiddle.uk/JkR5bg2O
SELECT username, activity
FROM (
    SELECT
        username,
        activity,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY starttime DESC) seq
    FROM activities
) AS a1
WHERE seq = 2 OR (seq = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM activities AS a2
    WHERE a2.username = a1.username
    AND a2.activity != a1.activity
))
ORDER BY username;

